# Papers that Originally Introduced the Concept of Inverse Perspective Projection

Tags: graphics, 3d, gpu, rasterizing

I am studying the rasterization algorithm and try to make a list of papers which were seminal in this area. For example "A Parallel Algorithm for Polygon Rasterization" would be one.

The one or group of papers I am looking for at the moment, are the papers that introduced the concept of interpolating vertex attributes (RGB, n, st, etc.) across the surface of a triangle using the inverse projection method.

Basically, my goal is to get back to the source of the technique.

Any other fundamental/seminal paper you could actually recommend in this area would be helpful as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question in part, the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouraud_shading) on Gouraud shading mentions Gouraud's PhD thesis and apparently a follow-up paper as sources.

> Gouraud, Henri (1971). Computer Display of Curved Surfaces, Doctoral
>   Thesis. University of Utah. Gouraud, Henri (1971).
>
> "Continuous shading
>   of curved surfaces". IEEE Transactions on Computers C–20 (6): 623–629.
>   doi:10.1109/T-C.1971.223313.

Comment: Looking now. Will give feedback as soon as I reviewed the sources. Thx

Comment: Unfortunately that's what I was afraid of. It's definitely a seminal paper but ... it speaks about linear interpolating while the scanline is being processed, it doesn't really specifically talk about the inverse projection issue. It doesn't also speak about evaluating a primitive attribute for any random point contained in the primitive (triangle, quad, etc.)